# How to make multi targets in one rule

Tags: makefile

In my work directory, I have some files called `foo.c`, `bar.c`, `baz.c`, each file defines some methods. And I have two files called `a.c` and `b.c`. Each is a single program using methods from `foo.c`, `bar.c` and `baz.c`. I compile the `a` and `b` with below Makefile

```
TARGETS := a b

OBJS := foo.o bar.o baz.o

all: $(TARGETS)

a: a.o $(OBJS)
    gcc $^ -o $@

b: b.o $(OBJS)
    gcc $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

However, the `rule a` and `rule b` is similar and if I have a new program named **c**, I have to write a another rule.

So can I make the `a` and `b` in one rule somethings like this:

```
$(TARGETS): $(OBJS) $(x.o)
    gcc -c $^ -o $@
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using pattern rules to compile objects, why not use them to create the executable as well?

```
%: %.o $(OBJS)
       gcc $^ -o $@
```

Or if you prefer to avoid match-anything pattern rules you can use static pattern rules:

```
$(TARGETS): %: %.o $(OBJS)
       gcc $^ -o $@
```

(secondary expansion is really overkill for this...)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion), e.g.,

```
TARGETS := a b c

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): $$@.o $(OBJS) 
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

The main benefit is that each target can have its own list of .o files. So if later on you need to add more .o files only for target `a`, you could do something like

```
#Shared by all targets
COMMON_OBJS := foo.o bar.o baz.o

.SECONDEXPANSION:
#Used only for target a
a_OBJS := obj1.o obj2.o
$(TARGETS): $$@.o $$($$@_OBJS) $(COMMON_OBJS)
```

and it will still work for other targets.

Comment: When I try this method, it doest not link `TARGET.o`.